# Can't implement this design pattern in Swift?

Tags: swift

I know this pattern has a name, don't recall what it is. Basically have a method that returns a transient/trampoline thing that manipulates the original via an API. `Mediator` possibly?

I've tried to implement that in a simple example in Swift playground:

```
struct Count {
    var value = 0

    func adjuster() -> Adjuster {
        return Adjuster(target:self)
    }
}

struct Adjuster {
    var target:Count

    func increment(delta:Int) {
        self.target.value = self.target.value + delta
    }
}

var f = Count()

f.adjuster().increment(13)
```

First thing this does is helpfully tells me that the `increment` method needs to be marked `mutating`. It's a little unclear to me why. I would get why if it was mutating it's own var, but not the var of another. Oh well. So I let the IDE insert mutating for me. But then it has issues with the last line "test" case. It produces this error:

```
...: error: cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value
f.adjuster().increment(13)
~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

I don't entirely grok what the issue is here. Nor does it offer to "fix it" for me. So what's going on here? How do implement this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change `struct` to `class` in order to make it work.

Because `struct` are copied by value, so in this line

```
return Adjuster(target:self)
```

Adjuster will get a new copy of target, and saved it. In `increment` method, you are trying to modify `self.target.value`, which means you are modifying `self.target`, so essentially modifying `self`.

But there is more problem, because `struct` is value type, so

```
var count: Count // count.value = 0
var adjuster = count.adjuster()
adjuster.increment(1)
```

You will expect `count.value` will be 1, however this is not the case. `count.value` will remain 0 and `adjuster.target.count` will be 1. You code now is now very confusing and you are wondering what's wrong.

The real problem is you are implementing design pattern from OOP with primitive for pure-functional pattern, so they don't work together nicely.

If you are tying to follow some best practice guide and prefer `struct` over `class`, you might as well using functional approach instead. i.e. no mutation

```
struct Count {
    let value = 0
}

func increment(count:Count, delta:Int) -> Count {
    return Count(value:count.value + delta)
}
```

Comment: Following cues from Apple (like lots of talks at WWDC), I keep trying to do things TheValueWay(tm). And I keep hitting walls like this. The more it happens, the more convinced I am that Pedantic Academics are taking over at Apple :( Anyway, your answer helped me see the problem right away, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

With a `struct` (unlike `class`) if your method mutates its property(-ies), it must be marked with `mutating` keyword.

In your case it should look like:

```
mutating func increment(delta:Int) { ... }
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID239):

> Structures and enumerations are value types. By default, the properties of a value type cannot be modified from within its instance methods.
>
> However, if you need to modify the properties of your structure or enumeration within a particular method, you can opt in to mutating behavior for that method. The method can then mutate (that is, change) its properties from within the method, and any changes that it makes are written back to the original structure when the method ends.

*"I would get why if it was mutating it's own var, but not the var of another."*

Reason why it still complains about "mutating", although it's not its own property, but the property of another, is that both are value-types.  This means that if you change the property of `Count` within `Adjuster`, you still modify `Count` as well (it's a value-type, not an object).  Hence the need for `mutating`.

I do not see the implementation of `Foo`, so I can not say exactly why the last error message, but I guess it has the same root-cause, that is, value types are not the right thing to accommodate design-patterns.  So, you might be better off with classes, not structs.

Comment: Durh. Foo should have been Count. Changed that enroute of the copy-paste. Fixed.

Comment: Oh.  Then it's indeed about big difference b/w value- vs. reference- types.  Apple's value-type campaign is not a holy grail actually.  In the past everything was classes/objects, even the things that were better off as values.  Now we have values, so now Apple puts an emphasis on those.  Still that does not render classes/objects suddenly useless.  In particular, Design Patterns are about class/object.  Perhaps, some other 4 guys could write another book about Value-type Design Patterns.